# Ошибки после переноса сайта

Tags: opencart

Перенес сайт, ошибки о том что нет доступа к файлам. В конфиге сменил кажется все верно.. в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну так написано же в чем - Permission denied

Comment: Можно развернутый ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас пишет что нет доступа к некоторым файлам.
Вам надо:

1. Проверить от имени какого пользователя работает сервер(nginx)
2. Поменять владельца рекурсивно для всей папки
3. Поменять права на папки согласно инструкции.

chmod 0755 или 0777 system/storage/cache/

chmod 0755 или 0777 system/storage/logs/

chmod 0755 или 0777 system/storage/download/

chmod 0755 или 0777 system/storage/upload/

chmod 0755 или 0777 system/storage/modification/

chmod 0755 или 0777 image/

chmod 0755 или 0777 image/cache/

chmod 0755 или 0777 image/catalog/

chmod 0755 или 0777 config.php

chmod 0755 или 0777 admin/config.php

Comment: Еще потребовалось следующее:                    chmod 777 system/storage/logs/error.log
chmod 777 system/storage/logs/ocmod.log
chmod 777 system/storage/logs/openbay.log

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: chmod надо было с параметром -R, тогда бы не потребовалось.